# Observable converted into kotlin - Issue

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have converted a few `JAVA` classes into `Kotlin` but I am getting `Type Mismatch Error` issue in Android Studio.

I am adding my code snippets along with the screenshot of the message in IDE for reference.

**JAVA CODE**

```
Disposable disposable = Observable.just(true)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.flatMap((Function<Object, ObservableSource<?>>) o ->
    Observable.zip(mModel.getSubLocalitiesFromStores(storeType, storeVerified),
        mModel.getLocalitiesFromSubLocalities(),
        (subLocalities, localities) -> {
            mLocalities = localities;
            mSubLocalities = subLocalities;
            return true;
        }
        ))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(res -> {
    setUpLocalitySpinner(spinnerLocalities);
    setUpSubLocalitySpinner(spinnerSubLocalities);
});
compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
```

**KOTLIN CODE**

```
Observable.just(true)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.flatMap({ o->
    Observable.zip<ArrayList<SubLocality>, ArrayList<Locality>, Boolean>(mModel!!.getSubLocalitiesFromStores(storeType, storeVerified),
        mModel!!.localitiesFromSubLocalities,
        { subLocalities, localities ->
            mLocalities = localities
            mSubLocalities = subLocalities
            true
        }
        )
} as Function<Any, ObservableSource<*>>)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe { res ->
    setUpLocalitySpinner(spinnerLocalities)
    setUpSubLocalitySpinner(spinnerSubLocalities)
}
```

**Issue (IDE Warning)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have just a lambda function that can be anything. Sometimes, the type inference doesn't work 100%, so you have to help it a bit

I don't have an IDE right now, but I'd say that adding the type should be enough. Something like:

```
Observable.zip<...>(...,
    BiFunction { subLocalities, localities ->
        mLocalities = localities
        mSubLocalities = subLocalities
        true
    }
)
```

Just as a side note, beware that one of the cool things of RxJava is the functional approach. Nothing happens if you don't want to (i.e. you invoke `subscribe()`) and all the effects are confined in the Observable flow. These assignments

```
        mLocalities = localities
        mSubLocalities = subLocalities
```

are introducing side effects that may become hard to track bugs in a future

Comment: i don't know why but still i am getting error on o-> "can not inter for this type of paramter"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `zip`smoothly at kotlin, you should add RxKotlin on your gradle

try Observables.zip. not Observable.zip